# Has INotifyPropertyChanging been removed from wp8.1 universal

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, inotifypropertychanged, devart

Just been trying to convert my app from Windows Phone 8.0 to Windows Phone 8.1 Universal/store app.

I was using Devart's LinqConnect to access my SQLite database and when I added the model to the project and did a compile and I received the following error.

`Error  1   The type or namespace name 'INotifyPropertyChanging' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Has I `INotifyPropertyChanging` been remove from wp8.1?

Update 1:
A few people have mentioned that it should be in `System.ComponentModel` namespace.
I just had quick look and intellisense say this is valid

`System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`

but this is not

`System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging`

Comment: According to the MSDN page, it is in Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. You're not missing the `using` statement are you?

Comment: As the error message says: make sure you are including the necessary DLL reference (System.dll) and that you are either specifying the type name as a fully-qualified name (i.e. `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging`) or that you have the necessary `using System.ComponentModel;` in your .cs file.

Comment: `Using System.ComponentModel` is already in the .cs file. The file is generated for me using Devart Entity Developer. This file works fine in Windows Phone Silverlight but not universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INotifyPropertyChanging is not used by Windows Runtime apps (Store or Phone). It is not present in the .Net Framework for Windows Store apps. The best way to tell if something is present is to use Visual Studio's object browser since it will read the live metadata.

It is available for Windows Phone Silverlight apps.

If you have legacy code which implements it you may be able to stub that out by creating your own INotifyPropertyChanging definition. This will work within your own code, but you'll need to remove any behavioural dependencies on system code calling it.

Comment: Thanks for that Rob, I assumed this was the case but I wanted to check because I couldn't seem to find anything searching on google.